# Toggleable button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This toggleable button that is made with jQuery doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggleableButton').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
        function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
        };
    });
});
```

It should change opacity when clicked.
What is the problem with it? (NOTE: I'm doing this with a `div` element.)

Comment: Could you explain what this code should do? Just define a function wont call it.

Comment: use browser console to check for errors. You made syntax error trying to implement animation callback. Console will tell you about this error

Answer (score 2):

click only accepts one function, you'll have to create the toggle effect yourself, you can use jQuery's data to store a simple flag, and then on each click reverse the boolean in that flag to toggle the fading effect:

```
$('#toggleableButton').on('click', function() {
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');
    $(this).fadeTo('slow', flag ? 1 : 0.5);
    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aqe6x/1/)

Comment: Whoa there, explain what this code does because i started lerning jQuery a day ago!

Comment: @avaragecoder it is more js than jquery, get some online courses, read docs.

Comment: I would to add "stop()" here before FadeTo();

Comment: @eicto I learn from Codecademy, i haven't got to that level yet!

Comment: @avaragecoder I personally not like Codecademy, I searched the resources which can teach young js hackers, but this one is boring and not show js beauty.

Comment: I'm doing this with a **DIV** element, **not** a **BUTTON** element.

Comment: @avaragecoder - doesn't matter, you could be doing it with your grandma for all I care, it's still the same code.

Comment: @adaneo If i were to post the **whole** HTML, you would understand.

Comment: @adaneo [I would report if i knew how to!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Just hit the flag button under my answer? I've read the rules, and I brought my sense of humor, which is more than you did.

Comment: @adeneo You? Sense of humor? THen who was the one who said 'you could be doing it with your grandma for all I care'? Me or you?

Comment: @adeneo Ohhh... I forgot to install jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you wanted to fadeout and fadein on complete, but you made just closure here. This should fix it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggleableButton').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5,
        function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
        });
    });
});
```

if you want to toggle  0.5/1 on each click, then @adeneo's answer.